# Spring issue with Transaction marked for rollback only

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am trying to improve my design for persisting the entities in my web app and especially how i handle exceptions coming from the service / dao layers.

I have this very simple `StrengthUnit` entity that has 2 fields, `id` and `name`, and of course only the `name` is entered by the user when saving.

My old (weird) way of handling a `ConstraintViolationException` was to prevent it from happening in the first place by first checking if the name was assigned to an existing entity and only allowing the call to my save method if it didn't.

Since Hibernate can already handle things like that by throwing a `ConstraintViolationException` I want to take advantage of that. I have built what I believe should be solid logic but i'm getting an error in a specific scenario : If I try to persist an existing `name`, my code catches the exception, adds an error to the result object and the view is returned with the error below the `name` field.  If I then try to persist a valid, not already present `name`, this exception is thrown :

TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit

It looks like the transaction is not "resetting" when the exception occurs and i'm not quite sure how to handle this since I don't handle transactions myself, my service class is marked with the `@Transactional` annotation.

Below is the relevant code :

Controller method (I have commented my old style that works perfectly):

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/newStrengthUnit"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveStrengthUnit(@Valid StrengthUnit strengthUnit, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
{
    if (result.hasErrors()) 
    {
        return "strengthUnitDataAccess";
    }
    /*if (!strengthUnitService.exists(strengthUnit.getName()))
    {
        strengthUnitService.saveStrengthUnit(strengthUnit);
    }
    else
    {
        FieldError error = new FieldError("name", "name", strengthUnit.getName() + " already exists!");
        result.addError(error);
        return "strengthUnitDataAccess";
    }*/
    try
    {
        strengthUnitService.saveStrengthUnit(strengthUnit);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        FieldError error = new FieldError("name", "name", strengthUnit.getName() + " already exists!");
        result.addError(error);
        return "strengthUnitDataAccess";
    }
    return "redirect:/strengthUnits/list";
}
```

Service :

```
@Service("strengthUnitService")
@Transactional
public class StrengthUnitServiceImpl implements StrengthUnitService
{
    @Autowired
    StrengthUnitDao dao;

    @Override
    public void saveStrengthUnit(StrengthUnit strengthUnit) 
    {
        dao.saveStrengthUnit(strengthUnit);
    }
}
```

Main DAO (which all DAOs extend) :

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> 
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao()
    {
        this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) 
this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    protected Session getSession()
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    protected CriteriaBuilder getCriteriaBuilder()
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getByKey(PK key) 
    {
        return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    }

    public void persist(T entity) 
    {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity)
    {
         getSession().delete(entity);
    }
}
```

DAO :

```
@Repository("strengthUnitDao")
public class StrengthUnitDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, StrengthUnit> 
implements StrengthUnitDao
{
    @Override
    public void saveStrengthUnit(StrengthUnit strengthUnit)
    {
        persist(strengthUnit);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

***EDIT***

As requested, here are the stacktraces.  The first one is when i try to insert a known duplicated value, the second one is when i change the value to a known good one immediately after.

Expected exception when unique constraint is violated:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:241)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:755)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:594)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:487)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy467.saveStrengthUnit(Unknown Source)
at mdhis_webclient.controller.StrengthUnitController.saveStrengthUnit(StrengthUnitController.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:745)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2934)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3434)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:477)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3170)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2384)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)
... 48 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_fultcxtq254cq6p4g0s5ud9ca'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblStrengthUnit'. The duplicate key value is (%).
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:727)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
... 66 more
```

Abnormal exception when subsequent valid name is added:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:586)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:487)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy467.saveStrengthUnit(Unknown Source)
at mdhis_webclient.controller.StrengthUnitController.saveStrengthUnit(StrengthUnitController.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:745)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)
... 48 more
```

Hibernate configuration class (all my config is done programmatically):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"mdhis_webclient.configuration"})
public class HibernateConfiguration 
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() 
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"mdhis_webclient.entity"});
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
 }

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() 
{
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    try
    {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        if (hostName.compareTo("Martin-Beast") == 0)
        {
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SRV2012MD;InstanceName=ADT;DatabaseName=MDHIS");
            dataSource.setUsername("sa");
            dataSource.setPassword("xxxxxxxx");
        }
        else if (hostName.compareTo("LCAN10472DQ32") == 0)
        {
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/MDHIS;InstanceName=ADT");
            dataSource.setUsername("sa");
            dataSource.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxx");
        }
        else
        {
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.5:58616;DatabaseName=MDHIS");
            dataSource.setUsername("adt");
            dataSource.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxx");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ignored) {}
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() 
{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class","net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    //properties.put("hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    //properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none");
    return properties;        
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) 
{
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
    return txManager;
}
```

Comment: Never catch and swallow exceptions that breaks transaction management just as you are experiencing now.

Comment: What would be an alternative that would allow me to intercept the ConstraintViolationException without breaking it?  I'm currently doing pretty much the exact same thing for delete transactions and it works just fine but then again they are probably handled differently by Spring.

Comment: No you aren't doing the same thing... Check your `delete` and `persist` method in your `AbstractDao` the `persist` is the one that does a catch-and-swallow whereas the `delete` doesn't. So no you aren't doing the same thing and no they aren't handled differently. Let me rephrase my initial comment to *within a transaction you should never catch and swallow an exception*. Springs transaction management needs the exception to determine if it needs to commit or rollback as it doesn't see it (due to the swallow) it will try to commit, which fails (as you noticed).

Comment: Sorry i get what you're saying and i forgot to change this.  This was an attempt i made at clearing the session if an error happened to see if that would do the same thing but the issue also happens without this bit, i will change it in my original post.

Comment: If that is the case then your service isn't the actual transactional boundary. Add the actual stacktrace you get and your configuration for hibernate.

Comment: Please format the stack traces as I can hardly see which is which.

Comment: formatted correctly now

Comment: Could you add a better split (so that it are 2 separate code blocks)? And could you add your hibernate configuration.

Comment: added both as requested